# Combine 2 properties value into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

i'm new in Javascript and I need to convert this:

```
car :[ 
    { name: "Bwm", color:"red" },
    { name: "Ford", color:"black" },
    { name: "Ferrari", color:"yellow" },
];
```

To:

```
anotherObject: {
    Bwm: "red",
    Ford:"black",
    Ferrari:"yellow"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
car = [ 
    { name: "Bwm", color:"red" },
    { name: "Ford", color:"black" },
    { name: "Ferrari", color:"yellow" },
];

var anotherObject = {};
for (var i = 0, len = car.length; i < len; i++){
  anotherObject[car[i].name] = car[i].color;
}

console.log(anotherObject);
```

Note that you have a sintax error when you declare the `car` var, replace ':' by '='.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this.

```
var car = [ 
    { name: "Bwm", color:"red" },
    { name: "Ford", color:"black" },
    { name: "Ferrari", color:"yellow" },
];

var anotherObject = {};

car.forEach(function (item,i) { 
    anotherObject[item.name] = item.color;
});

console.log(anotherObject );
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, I'm glad to hear it from you. I'll appreciate if you could accept my answer or give me an up vote. :) thanks

Comment: Hi Jacobi, this is my firts time here in stackoverflow so i have not enough points to give you an up to you but dont worry i will.

Greetings from colombia

Comment: Ok, no problems, I forgot this detail... :)

Comment: Hi Jacobi, here is your Up :)

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over the first object and populate the second object.

```
var car = [ 
     { name: "Bwm", color:"red" },
     { name: "Ford", color:"black" },
     { name: "Ferrari", color:"yellow" },
];


var anotherObject = {};

for (var i in car)
{
    anotherObject[car[i].name] = car[i].color;
}

console.log(anotherObject);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qz5vgre7/

Answer (score 0):

Simply reduce the old array to the new object:

```
var anotherObject = car.reduce(function(obj, value) {
  obj[value.name] = value.color;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

You don't have to worry about array indices this way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle objects and arrays in javascript.

All the above answers are great examples of that.

I want to add another way to achieve this using the map or forEach functions.

The map function allows you to apply a function on each item of the array and return a replacing value.
The forEach function is similar to the map function but has no return type.

Using the forEach function

```js
var car = [{
  name: "Bwm",
  color: "red"
}, {
  name: "Ford",
  color: "black"
}, {
  name: "Ferrari",
  color: "yellow"
}, ];

var anotherObject = {};
car.forEach(function(item) {
  this[item.name] = item.color;
}, anotherObject);
```

Using the map function

```js
var car = [{
  name: "Bwm",
  color: "red"
}, {
  name: "Ford",
  color: "black"
}, {
  name: "Ferrari",
  color: "yellow"
}, ];

var anotherObject = car.map(function(item) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[item.name] = item.color;
  return obj;
});
```